# Doctrine2 One to One Relation parent id not saved in child

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some problem with relation saving.
I have users and profiles.
Not all users have profiles so i decided that profiles is owner of this relationships.
But when i create user. I have user form and profile form.
I have

```
$user = new Entity\User();
$profile = new Entity\Profile();
$user->setProfile($profile);
```

i User object i have

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="My\InfoBundle\Entity\Profile",cascade={"persist", "remove"},  mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $profile;
```

in Profile i have

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User",   inversedBy="profile")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
```

So when i save it, user_id not save in profile table. And i have not relation betwean user and profile.
Can i fix this? Or i should chnage owning in this relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User {
    public function setProfile(Profile $profile) {
        $this->profile = $profile;
        $profile->setUser($this);
    }
}
```

<s>Edit : For OneToOne relationship you mustn't use `mappedBy` and `inversedBy`.</s>

Comment: But why i mustn't use. Ofiicial documentation said: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: You're right. I thought that because I don't use this in a project and it works.